# Ubuntu 14.04 lts have asus tp500l touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad

I tried to use touchpad on ubuntu 14.04 lts and I have a asus TP500L touchscreen coumputer I tried to install a driver but I could not find any drivers. What to do?(sorry for the spelling)

Comment: Run `xinput list` in a terminal and edit the output into your answer.

Comment: Please give output of "dmesg | grep pnp"

Answer (score 0):

check this maybe can help you with your problem

http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2013/05/28/ubuntu-13-04-and-the-fight-for-the-mouse/